# Vertical alignment of tags differs between Ask page and inline tag editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, editor

If you are trying to edit tags, `span`s with tags are on the middle of block:

> [image]

If you are trying to create new questions, top padding of this block is greater than bottom:

> [image]

Alternately see them side by side (inline tag editor on the left, [the ask page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on the right):

> [image] [image]

On question creation `div`, that surrounds `span`s with tags, has class `multi-line`. If you remove it, everything will be fine.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SO: [Tags misaligned on ask question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374087/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed on Friday Sept. 14 - code intended for the internal Teams editor (a multi-line, wrapping tag editor) snuck into the public sites without associated styles (or consideration of what guidance is needed for tagging on public sites). Jisoo corrected this by limiting this behavior to Teams.